# adjust_pan behavior in Webview in fullscreen

Tags: android

I am trying to solve the issue that in my Webview, when a user selects a textfield, the keyboard that appears covers the text field below.
Instead, I need a behavior where the text field is moved right above the keyboard, like what the flag SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN would do.

Based on testing, it seems like by default on a Webview, it is displaying the keyboard below the field.
But my WebView is in fullscreen. I am calling this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) in my activity);
and this seems to make android stop doing the default 'pan and scan' behavior.

I've tried to call
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
and even
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
but that did not fix it.

I need to set the activity to fullscreen because I want to hide both the title bar and the status bar, so removing it is not an option unless there is another way to hide the status bar.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove FLAG_FULLSCREEN flag. There is a bug somewhere in the OS machinery and with some digging around i have found the following:

- without any extra scroll view around web view adjustPan never worked for me. Unfortunatelly the add scroll view also not always helps.
- adjustScroll works for me when FLAG_FULLSCREEN is not present for the activity the webview is in.

So to sum it up the safest option to go with when it comes to WebView is adjustResize not full screen activity.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.